# AI 100 Test the Face Detection API exercise

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zpb0.jpg) Hi I am doing this exercise Test the Face Detection API from this page given in this link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/identify-faces-with-computer-vision/8-test-face-detection?pivots=python

When I execute the command given below in Visual Studio Code on Python 3.5.3 64 bit, I am getting an error saying from keyword is not supported in this version. I've tried Python 3.7.4, and 3.8.6 and there also I am getting the same error.

**Code**

```py
import os
from msrest.authentication import CognitiveServicesCredentials
from azure.cognitiveservices.vision.face import FaceClient
```

**Error Message**

```
At line:2 char:1
+ from msrest.authentication import CognitiveServicesCredentials
+ ~~~~
The 'from' keyword is not supported in this version of the language.
At line:3 char:1
+ from azure.cognitiveservices.vision.face import FaceClient
+ ~~~~
The 'from' keyword is not supported in this version of the language.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ReservedKeywordNotAllowed
```

Please advise how to fix this issue.

Comment: This looks like a Powershell error message. Are you running Python code in Powershell?

Comment: @ForceBru - based on the attached screenshot, that appears to be exactly what the OP is doing. Good catch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you're using the Python extension for VSCode.

As it is merely an interpreter that runs on PowerShell, you will still need to prepend your command with python for it to work, such as `python script.py` in the Visual studio code.

Comment: Please edit your answer to contain formatted text, not an image of text. This [meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/272109) lists many reasons why this is really important (even if you do keep the screenshot, formatted text is important).

Comment: It is `python script.py` as mentioned in the text, this is just an illustration of where you have to do it. Pls let me know if this helps.

Comment: Please read the meta post I linked to. The issue is that many people will not be able to see such an image. Also, it's impossible to copy/paste from an image. There are many other reasons why this is problematic, all listed in that meta post.

Comment: @singhh-msft, and others Thanks a lot for your replies. Yes I was using Python extension for VSCode. After using python script.py I got the desired output.